# path.IsAbs returning incorrect result for Windows paths

Tags: go, path, absolute-path

Documentation of [path.IsAbs](https://godoc.org/path#IsAbs) says that *IsAbs* reports whether the path is absolute. I have a function in my code that checks if first argument is absolute and if it's not, it creates an absolute path.

```golang
func getPath() string {
    var dir string
    fmt.Printf("first arg -> %s and is it abs? %t\n", os.Args[1], path.IsAbs(os.Args[1]))
    if path.IsAbs(os.Args[1]) {
        dir = os.Args[1]
    } else {
        var currentDir string
        currentDir = filepath.Dir(os.Args[0])
        dir, _ = filepath.Abs(path.Join(currentDir, os.Args[1]))
    }
    return dir
}
```

The output is `first arg -> C:\Users\Mohammad\Music\Uncategorized\Telegram and is it abs? false`

But the first argument is absolute, so where I'm missing?

Comment: Go's documentation is different from what people seem to be used to. For Go packages you should actually read the package documentation (or type documentation) too and not just the method or function documentation. When in doubt: Read the documentation and start at the top reading everything (at least the package documentation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://golang.org/src/path/path.go#L203) of this function it is obvious that it simply checks if the first character of the path is `/`. This means it assumes a UNIX style of path and not the Windows style with a drive letter. But this behavior is by design and it is also well documented. Right at the beginning of [the documentation](https://godoc.org/path#IsAbs) it explicitly says:

> The path package should only be used for paths separated by forward slashes, such as the paths in URLs. **This package does not deal with Windows paths with drive letters** or backslashes; to manipulate operating system paths, use the path/filepath package.

Thus, follow the documentation and use the correct package for your specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

For windows os you can use

```
C:\\Users\\Mohammad\\Music\\Uncategorized\\Telegram
```

or

```
C:/Users/Mohammad/Music/Uncategorized/Telegram
```

they should work perfectly in your case.

Answer (score 0):

While path.IsAbs "simply checks if the first character of the path is /." as mentioned in another answer, [filepath.IsAbs](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.18/src/path/filepath/path_windows.go#L39-L57)
actually does checks regarding beginning with a volume, etc. for Windows.  As such filepath.IsAbs might be what you want to use in this case

```
// IsAbs reports whether the path is absolute.
func IsAbs(path string) (b bool) {
    if isReservedName(path) {
        return true
    }
    l := volumeNameLen(path)
    if l == 0 {
        return false
    }
    // If the volume name starts with a double slash, this is a UNC path.
    if isSlash(path[0]) && isSlash(path[1]) {
        return true
    }
    path = path[l:]
    if path == "" {
        return false
    }
    return isSlash(path[0])
}
```